# Xamarin.Forms Firebasepushnotification plugin OnNotificationOpened event causes app to restart for android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, plugins, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to handle a notifications opening on android that I've sent through Google's FCM on the SharedProject level by using "Plugin.FirebasePushNotification" plugin and subscribing to "OnNotificationOpened" event.

When I try to open the notification while the app is in the background I'm able to hit a breakpoint inside "OnNotificationOpened" event but after the work inside the event ends the App const. is hit and the application restarts.

I want the application to continue from its last state and hit "OnResume" method that is located inside the App class.

I've done some research about it online and almost all of them were about how splash activity might cause this issue so I've disabled my splash activity by turning the whole "SplashActivity.cs" file into a comment except  the namespace and usages and implemented the wanted features of splashactivity(style) inside the "MainActivity" class after that I made sure my "MainActivity" class was the only activity that had it's "MainLauncher" attribute set to true but the problem continues.

Here are the relevant classes:

**FirebaseReg.cs**

```
public class FirebaseReg
    {
        public static void FirebaseInit()
        {
            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh += (s, p) =>
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"TOKEN : {p.Token}");
                CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.Subscribe("defaultTopic");
            };

            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationOpened += (s, p) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    //Breakpoint hits here and I'm able to finish all my work without any exceptions 
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            };

            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationAction += (s, p) =>
            {
            };

            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += Current_OnNotificationReceived;
        }

        private static void Current_OnNotificationReceived(object source, FirebasePushNotificationDataEventArgs e)
        {
            //DO WORK
        }

}
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static Uri ServerUri = new Uri(" ");
    public static bool IsInForeground { get; set; } = false;

    public App()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent(); //After the work in OnNotificationOpened ends breakpoint goes here
            Application.Current.UserAppTheme = OSAppTheme.Unspecified;
            
            Application.Current.MainPage = new LoginPage();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           
        }

    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        IsInForeground = true;
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        IsInForeground = false;
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        IsInForeground = true;
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
[Activity(Label = "TestProject1", Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.ActionBar);
            // Name of the MainActivity theme you had there before.
            // Or you can use global::Android.Resource.Style.ThemeHoloLight
            base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);


            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this);
            UserDialogs.Init(this);

            Xamarin.FormsGoogleMaps.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this ,Intent);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
        protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, intent);
            base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

**MainApplication.cs**

```
 [Application]
public class MainApplication : Application, Application.IActivityLifecycleCallbacks
{
    public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer) : base(handle, transer)
    {

    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);

        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelId = "DefaultChannel";
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelName = "defaultTopic";
        }


#if DEBUG
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, true);
            FirebaseRegister.FirebaseInit();
#else
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, false);
            FirebaseRegister.FirebaseInit();
#endif
    }

    public override void OnTerminate()
    {
        base.OnTerminate();
        UnregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }

    public void OnActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
    }

    public void OnActivityDestroyed(Activity activity)
    {
    }

    public void OnActivityPaused(Activity activity)
    {
    }

    public void OnActivityResumed(Activity activity)
    {
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
    }

    public void OnActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState)
    {
    }

    public void OnActivityStarted(Activity activity)
    {
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
    }

    public void OnActivityStopped(Activity activity)
    {
    }


}
```

Comment: `but after the work inside the event ends the App const. is hit and the application restarts.` What do you mean by above words? And what's the `App const`? In addition,I don't quite understand sentence：`I want the application to continue from its last state and hit "OnResume" method that is located inside the App class.` either . Can you explain that in detail?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT "App const." is the App constructor that is located inside "App.xaml.cs" file and what I mean when I say I want the application to continue from its last state is that I don't want the application to restart when I click on the notif. if the app is already present in the background,I just want android to continue my App from its last state and hit the "OnResume" method the same affect applies when you click on an app that is sent to background it hits the "OnResume" method I want the same affect to apply when I click on my notif. if the app is already in the background

Answer (score 1):

From the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP), it states this:

> If it has declared its launch mode to be "multiple" (the default) and
> you have not set FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP in the same intent, then it
> will be finished and re-created; for all other launch modes or if
> FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is set then this Intent will be delivered to
> the current instance's onNewIntent().

That's why your app is restarting.

The `launchMode` attribute of the activity affects how the activity is launched.

`singleTop`, `singleTask`, or `singleInstance` should be used to prevent the notification intent from creating a new activity instance.

The flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` doesn't influence a new activity being created, but makes the launched activity the root of a new task.

For more, check:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack